# SEO: Remove old restaurant from Google

Tags: seo

Well, the title sounds a bit weird.

There once was a little restaurant on the corner which was really bad and had to close soon. Let's call this one *"Pukie"* in the town of *"New Haven"*.

Now, there is a new one, pretty good and coincidentally my client. Let's call it *"Goodie"*. I made them a website and a Google+ page and a My Business entry and so on.

So basically, they have the same address.

When you google *"pizza new haven"* you will get all the results of *Pukie*, which is also marked as "permanently closed" by Google.
Customers will have to google *"goodie new haven"* to see the correct My Business entry and directions.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Well, where else to ask then?

Comment: Try the google local business forum, or see here https://support.google.com/business/answer/4578106?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the cached version of your webpage because it contained content that you've removed and don't want indexed, you can request the cache removal from your google webmaster account. they will check to see that the content on the live page is different from the cached version and if so, they will remove the cached version. they'll automatically make the latest cached version of the page available again after few days (and at that point, they will likely have recrawled the page and the cached version will reflect the latest content).